# How to know if my system allows monitoring?

Tags: monitoring, microphone

Someone once told me "If your system allows "Monitoring" that will echo the microphone through your own speakers to test."

But they didn't tell me how to find out if their specific system allows this monitoring.

So, how would a person know or do this?

Comment: Hm, I think I will start a question "How to know which system Frank McLean has?".. Now seriously, Linux Windows Mac all of them has this option..

Answer (score 0):

Often, this sort of facility is provided by an audio recording application.

For example

[image: Audacity Preferences]

Note the "Software Playthrough" option.